# Nginx randomly refuses SSL connections

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, node.js

I am running the website https://telerandom.com (NodeJS server, port 9576) behind an Nginx reverse-proxy. It *usually* works, but on occasion, it begins to refuse all SSL connections from certain users (while working perfectly normal for everyone else).

This period of refusing SSL connections usually lasts for about 45 minutes, and then things go back to normal. I have noticed that devices on the same network (e.g. my laptop and my phone on the same WiFi network) experience these outages at the same time. However, if I were to disconnect my phone from WiFi and use cellular data, it can connect to the website normally.

Both port 80 and 443 are open on the server. I get these messages in my error log when the connection is refused:

```
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 post event 0000000002327BB0
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 post event 000000000233B3C0
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 delete posted event 000000000233B3C0
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 http run request: "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=_32mgWR6o50vOl7pAAAC"
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 event timer del: 20: 1437784644303
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 event timer add: 20: 90000:1437784669313
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 delete posted event 0000000002327BB0
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 http run request: "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=_32mgWR6o50vOl7pAAAC"
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 SSL_read: 7
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 SSL_read: -1
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 SSL_get_error: 2
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 send: fd:20 7 of 7
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 event timer: 20, old: 1437784669313, new: 1437784669313
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 post event 0000000002327AE0
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 post event 000000000233B2F0
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 delete posted event 000000000233B2F0
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 http upstream request: "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=_32mgWR6o50vOl7pAAAC"
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 http upstream process upgraded, fu:0
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 event timer del: 20: 1437784669313
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 delete posted event 0000000002327AE0
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 http upstream request: "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=_32mgWR6o50vOl7pAAAC"
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 http upstream process upgraded, fu:1
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 recv: fd:20 3 of 4096
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 SSL to write: 3
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 SSL_write: 3
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 recv: fd:20 -1 of 4096
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2015/07/24 20:36:19 [debug] 1695#0: *92 event timer add: 20: 90000:1437784669313
```

And here is my configuration file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name telerandom.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name telerandom.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl/telerandom/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl/telerandom/cert.key;
    ssl on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/telerandom.com.access.log;
    error_log             /var/log/nginx/telerandom.com.error.log debug;

    location / {

      proxy_http_version      1.1;
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";

      # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:9576;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:9576 https://telerandom.com;
    }
}
```

Restarting Nginx and the server doesn't resolve the problem, nor does restarting the client devices. Additionally, this has happened on multiple networks (at one point it began happening on my phone's cellular data) and has happened to people other than myself. Also, while the problem is occurring I can also connect to similarly-configured SSL sites behind nginx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special in the server log which shows a problem at the site of nginx. But, you description clearly indicates a problem in the clients  network, i.e.

- only clients in the same network are affected
- all clients in the same network are affected
- if client connects to another network while experiencing the problem, the problem no longer occurs

This it might simply be a problem with the reliability of your client network. Since you are talking about Wifi it might be some interference by some broken electronic device (microwave, vacuum cleaner etc) and should not only affect the SSL connections to this single server but also other connections, i.e. at least make them slow or unreliable. Of course it could also be an attacker in the network, the Wifi getting saturated by someone transferring lots of data (backup job?) etc. But I'm sure that it is unrelated to your nginx setup.

Comment: I should have added a few more details. This has happened on multiple networks (at one point it began happening on my phone's cellular data) and has happened to people other than myself. Also, while the problem is occurring I can also connect to similarly-configured SSL sites behind nginx

Comment: @DrAgonmoray: the `recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)` indicates connectivity problems. Maybe you employ some kind of DOS protection which slows down some networks or do you have some limits per IP address which would apply to all systems behind a NAT router because they share the same outgoing IP address.

Comment: Other websites on the same server (also behind Nginx) function normally and, to my knowledge, have never faced this issue. I just found something though: On devices that are experiencing the problem, telerandom.com resolves to 192.64.119.168, which leads to an Nginx server that appears to belong to my domain registrar.

Comment: I am marking your answer is correct because you knew that it wasn't a problem with my server - but I would still appreciate some help if you have any ideas :)